# PrimeQ[ Table[sum_(n=1)^(N)n!, {N,1,30}]]

Tags: wolfram-alpha

The PrimeQ[Table[...]] command used to work in Wolfram|Alpha back in 2012 but now it doesn't give any answer. Is there a substitute?

Comment: what do you want to find?

Comment: I just typed PrimeQ(11) into wolfram alpha and got "11 is a prime number", so it understands the notation.

Comment: It no long accepts multiple numbers such as PrimeQ[{1,2,3,4,5}] which is problematic for me.

Comment: I see...yes, you're right. I'll play with it a bit.

Comment: @Brian try `PrimeQ[#]&/@[{1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: Or PrimeQ[]/@{11,12,13,14,15}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @martin and @lulu, `PrimeQ[]/@[...]` works so that entries such as

`PrimeQ[]/@[Table [sum_(n=1)^(N)n!, {N,1,30}]]`

Gives the proper answer